# compare two objects of same class which contain list of objects

Tags: java, json, compare

I have two objects(which contain of list of objects) of same class.I need to find whether both are same or not.

Consider below example:

```
class Device {

    String deviceName;
    String devLocation;
    String devType;
    String devID;

    public String getDeviceName() {
        return deviceName;
    }

    public void setDeviceName(String deviceName) {
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
    }

    public String getDevLocation() {
        return devLocation;
    }

    public void setDevLocation(String devLocation) {
        this.devLocation = devLocation;
    }

    public String getDevType() {
        return devType;
    }

    public void setDevType(String devType) {
        this.devType = devType;
    }

    public String getDevId() {
        return devID;
    }

    public void setDevId(String devId) {
        this.devID = devId;
    }

}


class DevList {

        List<Device> deviceList;

        public List<Device> getDevices() {
            return deviceList;
        }

        public void setDevices(List<Device> deviceList) {
            this.deviceList = deviceList;
        }
    }
```

Need to compare two objects of DevList class.

Will get a new  DevList object for every regular interval of time.

Every time i need to verify current object with previous object and update DB if there is any difference else ignore.

The list(deviceList) in current and previous objects might not be in same order.

for example:

Consider below two objects which are in Json format(Please ignore json format errors).

Object 1:

```
{  
   "devList":[  
      {  
         "deviceName":"ABC",
         "devLocation":"India",
         "devType":"Router",
         "devID":"1111"
      },
      {  
         "deviceName":"XYZ",
         "devLocation":"India",
         "devType":"Router",
         "devID":"2222"
      }
   ]
}
```

Object 2:

```
{  
   "devList":[  
      {  
         "deviceName":"XYZ",
         "devLocation":"India",
         "devType":"Router",
         "devID":"2222"
      },
      {  
         "deviceName":"ABC",
         "devLocation":"India",
         "devType":"Router",
         "devID":"1111"
      }
   ]
}
```

We can do it by iterating lists in both objects by checking devID. But complexity would be M*N.

Is there any other way?

Comment: If you want two device lists to be considered equal when they differ only in their order, then you need use `Set<Device>` instead of `List<Device>`.
Be aware, then you also need to add proper `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` methods to your `Device` class.

Answer (score 0):

You could override `equals` in  `Device` to compare each `Device` object.

Something similar

```
class Device {

 ...
 ...
 //your getter and setter

    public boolean equals (Object obj)
    {
      if (Device.class != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
      }
      if (obj instanceof Device) {
            return (deviceName.equals(((Device) obj).deviceName) &&
                    devLocation.equals(((Device) obj).devLocation) &&
                    devType.equals(((Device) obj).devType) &&
                    devID.equals(((Device) obj).devID));
      }
      return false;
    }

}
```

Now, call **[`removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))**, which will remove same object list from `List1`

```
List1.equals(List2);
```

So, if both list has same object list, then `List1` would be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: First override equal method in Device Class
Step 2: override the equal() in your DevList class with 
with below logic
  1. use one Set collection 
  2. add object into it from 1st Object's list
  3. check size() of set
  3. add object from 2nd Object's list
  5. check size() of set every time you add from 2nd list
  6. if more than the size of one list it is not equal(**As Set will not keep duplicate value**)